# Datastax DSE: dse spark-submit ignores java properties passed

Tags: properties, apache-spark, datastax-enterprise

I have setup a simple project to expirement with spark. I use dse 4.6.2 (3).
When i submit the jar with the following command (in stand-alone mode not yarn):

```
dse spark-submit --driver-java-options "-Dloggging.path=/home/$USER/log/" --class com.SimpleSparkApp my.jar
```

The property `logging.path` appears in `spark.driver.extrajavaoptions` so i can do `sys.pros.get("spark.driver.extrajavaoptions")` and parse the string, obviously not the best thing to do. On the other hand, the property does not exist when i search for it with `sys.props.get("loggging.path")...`

Shouldn't the properties be applied to the driver's jvm?
Any ideas?